# Django filter a queryset based on the template name

Tags: python, html, django

In my Django App, I have 2 models. One called Post and one called Categories. When a user clicks on a category, I want only the posts that are in that category to appear in the category detail view. For example if a user clicks on the medical category, I only want the posts in the medical category to appear.

Models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    colorcode = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    sub_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    live = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

Views:

```
class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
model = Category

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CategoryDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['category_posts'] = Post.objects.filter(live=True)
    return context
```

Template:

```
{% for post in category_posts %}
    <div class="post">
        <div class="post-title">
            {{ post.title }}
        </div>
        <div class="post-author">
            {{ post.author }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `DetailView`, you have access to the actual object being rendered (in your case the `Category` instance) through `self.object`.

So in your `get_context_data` method you can do:

```
context['category_posts'] = Post.objects.filter(live=True, category=self.object)
```

Note that `self.object` might be `None` so you may want to deal with that case.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Will award you the answer when possible.